# Using database in AngularJS - where should I write DB connection code?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mongodb, angularjs

I'm now building up a web app using Node.js, AngularJS and either MySQL or MongoDB. However, when I tried to use AngularJS with a controller which includes datasets fetched from database, I wonder where I should write the code in...

I'm now writing in the following code (search.ejs, not including full portion (such as `html` tag)):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/searchController.js"></script>
<div ng-app class="row" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
<input ng-model="query">
<ul class="search">
<li ng-repeat="i in list" | filter:query">
<a href="{{i.url}}">{{i.name}}</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And I want to fetch data in `list` from database and use it. So here's `searchController.js` file:

```
function searchCtrl($scope){
    $scope.list = [
        {
            'name': 'Michael',
            'url': 'mic'
        },
        {

            'name': 'Bob',
            'url': 'bob'
        }
    ]
}
```

However, what I want to do is instead of writing out data in the `$scope.list` variable manually, use data in database of either MySQL or MongoDB. (And MySQL is my preferred language, but MongoDB seems like the better in this case, I think.) So how can I connect to DB?

I also have one file called `search.js`, which is the following one:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render("search", {
    }, function(err, res){
        res.render("index", {
            content: res
        });
    });
}
```

And finally, I also want to hear from you whether I should first save data from database to any file and use it by opening and closing the file, or I should directly connect to database whenever the request comes to fetch data, in terms of performance and security issues, (the data in database would be updated every day, so I have to run a script to automatically recreate the served file anyway).

Thanks.

Comment: I answered your first question but for the second one I didn't understand what is the file you need to open.

Comment: Thanks. What I meant in `saving to a file` is as follows: 1) fetch data from DB and save its result to a file. 2) Load the saved file in `searchController.js` and map its content to the value of `$scope.list` variable. 3) finally, access the variable from within `search.ejs` file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe the best practice is to have an http route that you can get the list from. Let's assume it's a list of articles, then you:

1. have a route in your web server from which you could : `GET /articles` (you could easily implement it using mongodb driver `collection` & `find` functions)
2. on your angular controller :

(client code)

```
function searchCtrl($scope, $http){
    $http.get("/articles").success(function(articles, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.articles = articles
    }
}
```

as for your second question, you could render the list from the server, but if you want to update the list, you will need to use `$http` regardless. moreover, note that angular templates use `{{}}`, so you might override them if you're not careful - that's why I think it's not a good practice.
if, however, you had some configuration you want to inject from your web server, then you could inject a code similar to this (as a script):

```
angular.module("myModule.configuration", []).constant('myConfiguration', {siteName:"http://www.my-site.com");
```

and then you could inject 'myConfiguration' to all your controllers (don't forget to add `"myModule.configuration"` to the dependencies array)

Comment: Thanks. Now everything is working fine. With more than two weeks passed since my original post and no single answer thereafter, I've had already been close to giving it up. Definitely want to upvote more than 1... Thanks a lot.